# Unable to deploy gatsbyJs + Netflify website - 5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, gatsby, netlify

I'm experiencing issues with deploying my Gatbsy website onto Netlify . Below is the failure error message in the logs

```
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! errno 1
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! sharp@0.32.1 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR!
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.32.1 install script.
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
5:12:32 PM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2023-07-06T22_12_32_741Z-debug.log
5:12:32 PM: Error during npm install
5:12:32 PM: Build was terminated: dependency_installation script returned non-zero exit code: 1
5:12:32 PM: Failing build: Failed to install dependencies
```

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.17.0",
    "gatsby": "^5.10.0",
    "gatsby-link": "^5.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls": "^5.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^5.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-google-gtag": "^5.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-gtag": "^1.0.13",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^6.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.8.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^6.10.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.10.0",
    "gatsby-react-router-scroll": "^6.10.0",
    "gatsby-remark-images": "^7.10.0",
    "gatsby-remark-relative-images": "^2.0.2",
    "gatsby-script": "^2.10.0",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^8.10.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.10.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^6.10.0",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.63.2",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1"
  },
```

have tried to delete my node_modules folder,  reinstall dependencies with npm, and install sharp, but none of that seems to solve the issue. Please, does anyone know what I could be missing?

Comment: I was just able to resolve the issue by setting my Netlify environment variable to node_version = 18.14.0, which matches my gatsby project node version.